# Timeout Error after running MySQL query in C#.Net

Tags: c#, mysql

I have written MySQL query as given below

```
"SELECT ad.UserId, l.name , Sum( ad.Amt ) AS Amount ,ad.UserDate FROM adm_advt_answer    ad" +
" JOIN adm_advt_question adq ON ad.Q_ID = adq.nID" +
" INNER JOIN adm_grp_registration l ON ad.UserId = l.userid WHERE adq.Buserid = '" +            
 lblusername.Text + "' AND adq.Active='Y' AND ad.UserDate > DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 WEEK )" + 
" GROUP BY ad.UserId"
```

My query is taking too long time so I get Timeout Error.
I have to get the result in Grid.

My Sample Output will be

```
CustomerName        TotalAmount      UserDate

xxx                  10            2/20/2014 13:01       
aaa                  14            2/17/2014 10:04    
dddd                 10            2/15/2014 9:31     
ccc                  1.4           2/20/2014 8:43        
eeee                 14            2/14/2014 10:04  
ssss                 14            2/20/2014 10:04
```

Comment: Did You try use EXPLAIN on this query ??

Comment: can you please let me know the syntax for it

Comment: You just run the query with EXPLAIN before the SELECT

Comment: Also, can you post the declares of the 3 tables, including the indexes they have.

Comment: when i added EXPLAIN before the SELECT command am getting error

Comment: Do you have phpmyadmin? If so take your SQL, make it into valid SQL (ie, get rid of the VB bits used to build up the string of SQL, and put in the values you are searching for), add explain to the front and execute it. What this should give you is details of the select, such as which indexes MySQL has chosen to use on each table in the query. But without the results of this or at least the table declares it is virtually impossible to help you. Explain manual page - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html